# import script not working after using sys.path.append

Tags: python, import, sys

I am learning about the working of modules and was trying to run my program and for that i needed to import my own module from a different directory, so, i learned that i need to use sys.path.append method to import my module but it did not work and gave me error

I tried this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/admin/Desktop/programming/pythonscripts/myscript.py')
for i in sys.path:
    print(i)
import myscript
```

it gave me the ModuleNotFoundError

What should I do to make my code run and if there is any other better way kindly recommend it.

Comment: Append the directory part only.

Comment: yes, appending only the directory worked